# Unity-based Android game screen cut diagonally in half under Lollipop (but not under Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, graphics

The screen in my Android phone is cut in half diagonally.

[image: IMG:]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I'm using Unity 3D game engine. After building it and installing it in my phone which is running Android Lollipop, the screen of the game I created is cut in half diagonally. I tried to install it in another phone running Android Jelly Bean, and it works properly.

I've searched many forums already. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does it work when running in an emulator with android 6?

Comment: now that is strange!

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find a solution @seji..

Comment: Can anyone helpi n this please?

Answer (score 1):

It is a Z position problem. you can either move all objects to -1(or less), or you can move the Quad(if that what you are using, to 1 (or greater), that will fix it